# ls | egrep | xargs rm

Tags: pipe, xargs

I have a group of files I'd like to remove at once.

```
ls | egrep \^New
```

The output is as expected,

```
New 1
New 2
New 3
```

but continuing the pipe with

```
| xargs -L rm
```

attempts to remove the input as space-delimited:

```
rm: New: No such file or directory
rm: 1: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don’t parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440). This should do the trick:

```
rm New*
```

Your approach is failing because `xargs` splits arguments up on whitespace by default, so it runs `rm` on `New`, `1`, `New`, `2` etc. You could work around that by splitting on newlines, but that won’t work with filenames containing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, `xargs` is breaking up the file names at the spaces. If you're using GNU `xargs` you can have it use a newline as the delimiter with the `-d` option. Example:

`ls | egrep \^New | xargs -d '\n' rm`

Comment: I don't think `xargs` has a `-d` option.

Comment: @erythraios `xargs -d` is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html). But the [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) provided by [GNU Findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), which is present in GNU/Linux systems, [does support it](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#xargs-options).

Comment: Either used `rm New*` or use `find . -type f -name "New*" -print0 |xargs -0 -r rm` .. both handle special char correctly (the later is recursive and it's very powerful)